# Problem with connecting and migrating database with Homestead

Tags: php, database, laravel, homestead

I am trying to connect to database with Homestead in Laravel. I get error

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
 password: NO)
```

when I php artisan migrate with git bash, and also in my browser when I refresh home page. I tried changing my .env and clearing cache but unsuccessfully. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=real-estate-laravel
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

hosts

```
192.168.10.10 real-estate-laravel.test
127.0.0.1 phpmyadmin.test
```

Comment: try changing DB_HOST to 192.168.10.10 --- though it's odd that it's saying 'root'@ localhost with no password.  Also DB_PORT should be 3306 by default...is your change deliberate?

Comment: If that doesn't work...```vagrant ssh``` in to homestead and try clearing caches again
```php artisan config:cache```

Comment: @JamesAllen Yeah, I tried with 192.168.10.10 and with 3306 and it doesn't work. And yes it is deliberate because I tried changing those addresses and none of them work. Also clearing caches don't work. I tried everything above.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

```
$ mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

And then, excute these statements.

```
$ mysql -u root mysql
$mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('your_password') WHERE USER='root';
$mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you face the unknown field Password error above use, then try this:

```
update user set authentication_string=password('your_password') WHERE user='root';
```

Finally, restart the daemon without the `--skip-grant-tables` option.

```
$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Now, You can connect with your new password.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Enter password

```
your_password
```

Comment: I update the password, but when I get to restart daemon step and it shows me to enter password, when I enter it says pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to restart mysql.service: Access denied